# Read csv files (more than 1) in r shiny and create new column for Filename

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, shiny, upload

I want to upload multiple *.csv files, rbind them and create new column named Filename with original csv filenames.

With basename() function I am only apply to get temp file name and not the original filename.

input$datafile$name gets the original file name but I am not sure how to mutate new column from this name.

Below is my code for reference.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 10000*1024^2)

ui <- shinyUI(
fluidPage(
titlePanel("Example Read and Merge with new Column for Filename"),
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel( fileInput("datafile", h5("Choose CSV file:"),
                          accept = ".csv",multiple = TRUE)),
  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("Raw_data_show"),
            verbatimTextOutput("results"),textOutput("filechosen"))
)))

server <- function(session,input, output) {

path <- reactiveValues(pth=NULL)

observeEvent(input$filechoose,{
path$pth <- file.choose()
})

output$filechosen <- renderText({

if(is.null(path$pth)){
  return()
}else{
  dirname(path$pth)
}
})

rawData <- reactiveValues(site = NULL)                               

observeEvent(input$datafile, { 
req(input$datafile)

  rawData$site <- input$datafile$datapath%>%
  purrr::map_df(~fread(.x)%>%mutate(FileName_2D = basename(.x)))

})

output$results = renderPrint({
input$datafile$name
print(paste("First File (input$datafile$name)[[1]])",(input$datafile$name)[[1]]))
print(paste("2nd File (input$datafile$name)[[2]])",(input$datafile$name)[[2]]))    
})

output$Raw_data_show <- DT::renderDataTable({
rawData$site
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Below is the image of the app so far.

[image: UploadCSV_rbind_createColumn]

Appreciate some inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `input$datafile$datapath` to read the file and `input$datafile$name` to add a new column with the file name. Use `map2_df` to pass both the values together and combine into one dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Example Read and Merge with new Column for Filename"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel( fileInput("datafile", h5("Choose CSV file:"),
                              accept = ".csv",multiple = TRUE)),
      mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("Raw_data_show"),
                verbatimTextOutput("results"),textOutput("filechosen"))
    )))

server <- function(session,input, output) {
  
  path <- reactiveValues(pth=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$filechoose,{
    path$pth <- file.choose()
  })
  
  output$filechosen <- renderText({
    
    if(is.null(path$pth)){
      return()
    }else{
      dirname(path$pth)
    }
  })
  
  rawData <- reactiveValues(site = NULL)                               
  
  observeEvent(input$datafile, { 
    req(input$datafile)
    rawData$site <- map2_df(input$datafile$name, input$datafile$datapath, 
                          ~fread(.y)%>% mutate(FileName_2D = .x))
    
    
  })
  
  output$Raw_data_show <- DT::renderDataTable({
    rawData$site
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```